# How to properly anchor wooden porch columns to concrete pad?

Tags: anchor, railing, porch, column

I have a country style front porch that has non structural wooden columns that are anchored to the overhang and hang to the floor, a concrete pad.  To stop the columns from moving around the builders wedged a shaved 2x4 between the column and the concrete.  A railing is strung on the columns.  Depending on the temperature decides how sturdy the columns are held in place and if anyone puts any weight on the railing a column will swing around.  How can I fix this?

Comment: When I fixed my 4x4 posts (covered with vinyl covering), I used a bottle jack on a piece of 4x4 to lift the roof section about a 1/2" or so, then placed the support underneath, then let the jack out to have a little bit of down pressure on the 4x4 and post base. This helped keep the posts in place for the last 8 years without issues. I guess that settling had finished as well, so there you go :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post base. There are several styles, this is one.

[image]

Comment: Some people also refer to these as "stand-offs."